# How to most efficiently check if two strings are different?

Tags: php, string

I have two very large strings. How can I compare them to tell if they're identical, or if one of them is different than the other? (That way I can leave the identical strings alone and process the ones that have changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare hash values, or create a wrapper class containing the string in question and a "changed" flag that is set to `true` each time the string is altered.

Comment: True, but to compare hash values, you must walk each string fully to generate the hash, and then walk the hash.  Hence it's at BEST `O(m + n + 1)` and at worst `O(m+n+c)` (where `m` is the length of one string, `n` is the length of the other, and `c` is the hashed length)...  And that's even ignoring the complexity of the hash function... Definitely not the most efficient way unless you're already storing the hash.

Comment: That's what I meant: Calculate and store the hash when a string is written, not on comparison.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to do:

```
$string1 == $string2
```

It does a bit-wise comparison of the strings, so should be *at worst* `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the smaller string.  I don't think you're going to get much better than that (short of keeping track of the strings and if they were changed, but the way your question is worded it seems like all you want to do is compare them).

Comment: I'd even assume I won't compare any bytes (not bits!) at all if the length is different. Not possible in C with 0-terminated `char` arrays, but perfectly possible in about every other language :)

Comment: @delnan: it uses the [`memcmp()`](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/memcmp.html) C function (See `zend_binary_strcmp` in [the source](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_operators.c)).